# Php MySQL case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been asked before. But nothing seems to work for me.

So I have this code below. What I am trying to do is Search in a database for table `product_description` and get the column `name` (this part so far works).The column name's collation is utf8_general_ci

```
   $SearchWord1 = "Squirl";
   $ExistingWord1 = "Banana";
   $ReplacerWord1 = "Orange";
```

I have 3 products:

```
name: SQUIRL banana pie
name: Squirl BANANA pie
name: SQUIRL banana pie
```

I want to search for Squirl,the search should grab both Squirl and SQUIRL.
The same goes for banana `$ExistingWord1` which is Banana and should also search for BANANA

```
    $sql1 = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord1%';";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    echo "<h1>Everything worked as planned</h1>";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

I read several posts on stackoverflow and nothing helped me thus far.

Comment: It would help if you'd link to those other SO posts you mention + explain **what** didn't work for you there.

Comment: Look in to a search server like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's me but I'm not sure to understand your question.

If all you want is to be sure to find the items you want regardless of the case, then you can probably use MySQL functions named UPPER(...) and LOWER(...) that allow you to convert a string in uppercase or lowercase respectively

For example :

```
SELECT name FROM product_description WHERE LOWER(name) = 'squirl';
```

Will match both Squirl, SQUIRL or squirl

Comment: Yes but i have Both upper and lower case Squirl squirl and SQUIRL

When i run my code it only updated the Squirl and Banana and ignores SQUIRL and BANANA

Comment: actually i don't understand your problem :) If $SearchWord1 now contains a lowercase string e.g. "squirl" instead of "Squirl", then you can easily use the code above to fit your needs :

"UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '$SearchWord1';";

Comment: Oh i understand you now.I will try it and get back to you

Comment: I just did one you said

Made the $SearchWord1 = "squirl"
$sql1 = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '$SearchWord1';";

Nothing seemed to happen though

Answer (score 0):

In mysql char, varchar and text case insensitive
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Make sure that your text doesn't contains characters from other language

Comment: It does't countain chars from other languages but it does add other lanauge chars

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is case insensitive by default.

You probably have a case sensitive charset or your column has `BINARY` type assigned to it.

With `BINARY` a and A are different, which is not what you want ofc.

reference: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875543/can-i-make-mysql-table-columns-case-insensitive).

Be careful tho - as CI tables could give you duplicate results when products / items have the same name and you don't fetch them by ID ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in MySQL text|string based searches are case insensitive.